# UPnP / DLNA Render on Linux

Tags: linux, dlna, upnp

I have a NAS serving as DLNA server, now sometimes, laid back as I as I am, I'd like playing a movie on my Linux Desktop and control it via DLNA App from my phone. I tried VLC and other media players but none of them showed up as renderer in my phone. I tried the app with different TVs where it worked.

Mind: I'm not looking into installing a "media center" operating system, just the single program to be used once in a while.

Comment: "a NAS" doens't help much, what the model? which other players you checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you mentioned that you don't want to install a media center operating system, you can simply install XBMC as a simple application (which is what I do at home) on your desktop.

If you use a Debian-based operating system, then you will find XBMC already and conveniently [packaged on the repositories](http://packages.debian.org/sid/xbmc).

It features (among other things, like consuming things via NFS, or SMB from your NAS), a [DLNA Renderer](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=UPnP/Client) that is as simple to use as the other sources of media.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know much about your setup (NAS model? Android or iOS phone? Which linux distro?) why don't you use your device as a mobile mouse?

This way you will control VLC directly from your phone.

[HippoRemote](http://hipporemote.com/lite)

> Turn your iPhone and iPod touch into a wireless keyboard and mouse for your computer.
>
> - Multi-touch trackpad
> - Split-screen keyboard & trackpad
> - Fullscreen keyboard with history
> - Full international character support
> - Thumb scrolling
> - Wake-on-LAN
> - Support for Windows, Mac, Linux

Answer (score 0):

http://hobbyistsoftware.com/android/vlc-more

is what i use. There are free alternatives but this one is more feature packed.

Control VLC direct from your phone, Its much quicker